# Having trouble in creating a while loop

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, while-loop

I have written CSS for two column layout and I have a "users" database with notes of the users.

So when I run a while loop like this: **while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))**

PHP should dynamically create html like this (depending on no. of users):

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div> 
            <!-- Notes of user 1 -->
        </div>

        <div class="col">
           <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
           <!-- Notes of user 2 -->
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

          <div class="col">
               <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
               <!-- Notes of user 3 -->
           </div>

           <div class="col">
              <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
              <!-- Notes of user 4 -->
           </div>

    </div>
```

If there's is only one user, html should be like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
        <!-- Notes of user 1 -->
    </div>

</div>
```

And similarly if there are 3 users, there should one row with two columns and another row with one column.

Is there any way to do that?

Edit: Added my php code here.

```
   <?php 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

   ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
        </div>

    </div>


   <?php  } ?>
```

Problem with that code is it's creating a new row with "one column" for every user. My goal is to have "two columns" in the row.

Comment: Show us your PHP.

Comment: *"I have written CSS for two column layout"* - what does this have to do with the question, along with the missing mysql and loop(s)? Question's unclear.

Comment: Put `<div class="row">` and everything until `</div>` in the `while` then close the while. Should do it. Your `one row with two columns and another row with one column` sounds like a CSS issue or possible you need to use modulus operator in PHP. Please add PHP to the question so we can see what you currently are doing..

Comment: @chris85 I believe it's dynamically-generated from relevant code they didn't show us.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah ye olde magic code, always my favorite.

Comment: and wishing you well with this. Clairvoyant coders are very hard to come by; I count myself in that.

Comment: @chris85 the OP's communications skills are not the best as per their other question too. ^ ^ ^ This is always a "sign" which one gets to read rather well after a certain time. I guess I am clairvoyant after all ^ ^ ^. I wasted enough time here.

Comment: @chris85  added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve things like that with the modulo operator (%) within loops.

```
$i = 0;
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rowsHTML = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $notesHTML = '<div class="col">
            <div class="col-content">'.$row['notes'].'</div> 
            <!-- Notes of user 1 -->
        </div>';

    if($i%2 == 0){
        $notesHTML = '<div class="row">'.$notesHTML;
        // check if its the last item and the row has to be closed after 1 col
        if($i+1 == $rowCount){
            $notesHTML = $notesHTML.'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $notesHTML = $notesHTML.'</div>';
    }

    $rowsHTML .= $notesHTML;
    $i++;
}
echo $rowsHTML;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: glad to be of help. feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Done. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$i = 0;

?>

<div class="row">

<?php 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    if($i>1 && $i%2==0) echo '</div><div class="row">';

    $i++;
?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-content"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></div>
    </div>

<?php  } ?>

</div>
```